# Is the order of Promise.all.then results guaranteed?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-harmony, es6-promise

Assume this scenario:

```
Promise.all( [p1, p2] )
.then( v => {
   //v[0] contains results of p1?
     });
```

Assuming that both p1 and p2 are resolved, is it safe to assume that v[0] will contain the result for p1 and v[1]will contain the result for p2? Or can I only assume that v will contain 2 values for each promise and cannot assume where each value is?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: The order is maintained with respect to the input.

Comment: I don't see why this is downvoted. It's a valid question.

Comment: Well, the title wasn't particularly good .. but I agree it's a valid question.

Comment: @FelixKling: I didn't downvote, but it's a duplicate not a valid question :-)

Comment: @Bergi: Even better :)